# Is 'not until' correct here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, negation, time

> A: So when did he let you know he was dating your ex?
>
> B: He didn't really. **Not until** recently.

Is 'not until' correct and idiomatic here? (if I intend it to mean that the guy dating the ex didn't tell B for a long time, but now has recently)

I have consulted a dictionary but am still not completely certain if it can be used in my context.

Comment: Try googling it: not until recently

Comment: Have Googled it but couldn't find any completely similar examples. That's why I asked the question, even though I am/was pretty sure that it's correct.

Comment: Well, you are right - it is correct.

Comment: You've already included the "negating" element in preceding ***didn't***. Note that ***Not until recently*** isn't really a "sentence" - it's just a sequence of words qualifying what came before. The entire utterance would be more traditionally "grammatical" as just ***He didn't really, until recently*** (where that second adverbial element could just as well be moved to the front, rather than *after* the primary assertion ***He didn't*** with the first adverbial element ***really***). The implication of that is you should think of ***until recently*** as a "component", not ***not until***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “not until” is used to emphasize that an event does not occur prior to a certain point in time.